# Prepaid credit for Google Hangouts

Tags: google-hangouts

I have a Skype account that allows me to phone overseas telephone numbers at a local rate.
Does Google Hangouts have a similar "prepaid" concept?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does - click on the little phone icon to switch to call mode.

[image]

Once done, click on the dropdown to add prepaid credit.

[image]